# Infinite potential well suddenly expanding

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, probability

> **Problem statement:** an electron is in its fundamental state in an infinite (1-dimensional) potential well, its walls being located at $x=0$ and $x=a$. Suddenly, the right wall moves from $x=a$ to $x=2a$. ¿What is the probability of the electron being in its fundamental state? And what's the probability of it being in its first excited state?

**As far as I got:** The first piece of information I have (the particle being in its fundamental state in the first potential well) gives me an initial condition my solution should fulfill. That is to say, if we denote as $\Psi(x,t)$ the electron's wave function *after* the potential expands, then necessarily $\Psi(x,0)=\phi_0(x)$, being $\phi_0(x)$ the particle's fundamental state in the first potential (just its spatial part, I'm unaware if there's a specific term for it). I also know from my lectures this fundamental state is given by:

$$\phi_0(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin(\frac{\pi x}{a}), \quad x\in (0,a)$$

and null otherwise. I also know the particle, once in the second potential, will be in a state of superposition of some or all of its bound states:

$$\Psi(x,t)=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n\phi_n'(x)e^{-iE_n't/\hbar}$$

where the prime (') symbol denotes these magnitudes are defined in the second potential. Imposing the initial condition, I get:

$$\phi_0(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n\phi_n'(x)$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin(\frac{\pi x}{a}) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n\sqrt{\frac{2}{2a}}\sin\left(n\pi\left(\frac{x}{2a}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$

Now, performing a Fourier trick, I get:

$$\int_0^{2a}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{a}\sin(\frac{\pi x}{a})\sin\left(m\pi\left(\frac{x}{2a}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)dx = \int_0^{2a}\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n \sin\left(n\pi\left(\frac{x}{2a}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\sin\left(m\pi\left(\frac{x}{2a}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\cdot dx$$

The second term is $0$ if $m\neq n$ and $C_n$ for $m=n$, so I get:

$$C_n = \int_0^{2a}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{a}\sin(\frac{\pi x}{a})\sin\left(m\pi\left(\frac{x}{2a}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)dx$$

which yields $0$ for every $n$. How can this be?

Comment: Just a note: you can write the trig function as: \sin

Answer (score 1):

The wave function for the first well is equal to zero outside its boundaries (since the walls are infinitely high), therefore in the last integral the limits of integration are **not from 0 to 2a, but from 0 to a**, which leads to a non-zero value of the integrals Cn for any n. Visually, they are equal to the (non-zero) area under the graph of the product of wave functions, which means a non-zero probability of being at any level n. For large n, it decreases as n increases.